# Animate background color from center to corners of a div [Sqaure shaped] using Javascript or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css, compass-sass

If possible you guys, can you help me with this animation?, the purpose of animation is to animate a background-color, **the color is what i want to animate not the div** cause the div contains another elements that I want to be always showing. 
The animation i'm looking for is to spread the color[gray of containing div] from center to corners of a square.
is there a way to do it in CSS, if not how about Javascript/Jquery/Jquery-ui? maybe sass or compass? I'm fine with any of the above here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyf4P/1/) and the code:

HTML:

```
     <div class="outer_box">
       <div class="inner_box_1"></div>

       <div class="inner_box_2"></div>

       <div class="inner_box_3"></div>

       <div class="inner_box_4"></div>
    </div>
```

a simple CSS that might help:

```
  .outer_box{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
   }
  .inner_box_1{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
   }
  .inner_box_2{
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
   }
  .inner_box_3{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
   }
  .inner_box_4{
    background-color: orange;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
   }
```

Comment: sounds like you need an animated radial gradient

Comment: @David Fregoli I'm not familiar with radial gradient animation(i searched it and its not what i'm looking for), I expect no gradients at all, if it has to come from a color to another then from transparent to gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am assuming that you do *not* require a gradient.

There could be pure CSS3 solutions, but this is the easiest hack I could think of using jQuery.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/pyf4P/2/**

You give a `position: relative` and transparent background to your `outer_box` div:

```
.outer_box {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 400px; height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then, have a dummy div inside that container and give it `position:absolute` starting from center, and with lower `z-index` than the container, and with your desired background color:

*Markup*:

```
<div class="outer_box">
    <div class="inner_box_1"></div>
    <div class="inner_box_2"></div>
    <div class="inner_box_3"></div>
    <div class="inner_box_4"></div>
    <div id="dummy"></div> <!-- this is the dummy -->
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
#dummy { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px; left: 200px;
    width: 1px; height: 1px;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: -5;
}
```

That's it. Now you can animate this dummy div using jQuery:

```
$('#dummy').animate({
    'width': '400px',
    'height': '400px',
    'top': '0px',
    'left': '0px'
}, 500);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
<div class="outer_box">
   <div class="inner_box_1"></div>

   <div class="inner_box_2"></div>

   <div class="inner_box_3"></div>

   <div class="inner_box_4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer_box
{
   width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.temp-back{
   z-index: -1 !important;
   position: absolute;
   background-color:gray;
}
```

JS

```
 $(".outer_box").prepend($("<div>").addClass("temp-back"));//once

 $(".temp-back").animate({margin:"0px", width:"400px", height:"400px"},4000);//OUT

 $(".temp-back").animate({margin:"200px", width:"0px", height:"0px"},4000);//IN
```