# How to create a smooth animated flowing button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm planning to change all the `input[type=submit]`s & `button`s in my website into this smooth animated flowing button.

So, how do I create this using HTML, JavaScript & CSS? Especially I made this GIF to post it in Stack Overflow. And I don't think, I've to post some codes in this question to explain it. :/

[image: Smooth]

**EDIT:** I don't want exactly Curls effect with bottom right to top left. It should start affecting from the area I click. In the next GIF I've clicked in the middle. Now please see the affect.

[image: Flowing]

I hope you can understand what I mean. **It should start flowing to the outside from the exact area I click.**

Comment: you want to exactly Curls effect with bottom right to top left ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hover.css, Checkout background transition in that
http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ . 
If you want exactly like the one you posted. you can always try some trial and error with hover.css

Answer (score 0):

you can easily make with simple css see this [click](http://littlesnippets.net/6-css-image-hover-effects-using-page-curls/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button:after {
    content: "";
    background: #90EE90;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 300%;
    padding-left: 350%;
    margin-left: -20px!important;
    margin-top: -120%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this , hope it is helpful.

```css
a {
padding: 20px 30px;
line-height:30px;
color:#fff;
font-size: 20px;
background:#ff0000;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
transition: all ease .6s;
overflow:hidden;
display: inline-block;
}

a span {
z-index:1;
position:relative;
}
a:after {
transform: scale(0);
background: #000;
position: absolute;
right:-200px;
bottom:-200px;
content:'';
border-radius: 100%;
transition: all ease .6s;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}

a:hover:after {
  transform:scale(1);
  transition: all ease .6s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Test</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

can be achieved by a small tweak from "Abhitalks" answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993216/animate-background-color-from-center-to-corners-of-a-div-sqaure-shaped-using-j)!

In html  :

```
<div class="outer_box" id="btn">
    <span>Button text</span>
    <div id="dummy"></div>
</div>
```

css :

```
 .outer_box{
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    text-align:center;
   }

#dummy { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px; left: 400px;
    width: 1px; height: 1px;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: -5;
}
```

Script :

```
$('#btn').on("click", function() {
    $('#dummy').animate({
        'width': '400px',
        'height': '400px',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '0px'
    }, 500);    
    //and any action to be done on click :)
});
```